# Distributed Solr Indexing from Drupal

Tags: 7, search

I want a sharded Solr environment so that I can distribute data and query accordingly. Started two solr instances as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch#Distributed_Search_Example).

Since Solr doesn't support (fully yet) writing automatically into different Solr instances, I have to do it manually.

I'm trying to do it in the following hook:

```
/* "node" is the module name. */
function node_apachesolr_index_document_build($document, $entity, $entity_type, &$env_id)
{
}
```

Note that I'm trying to change the `$env_id` by making it a reference parameter, since that's what I want to change based on certain logic. When the cron is run, I get the error:

> Warning: Parameter 4 to node_apachesolr_index_document_build() expected to be a reference, value given in module_invoke_all() (line 857 of /var/www/drupal-7.17/includes/module.inc)

since it messes up with existing calls.

Any idea how to workaround this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the function [hook_apachesolr_index_document_build](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_index_document_build/7)(), on line 373 of file [apachesolr.api.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/7), is not a reference value, instead directly a variable. So, the code should be:

```
function hook_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {

}
```

Also, from the code you use, I suspect the following possibilities:

1. You are adding the code to the core *node* module, which is never recommended, as one should [**never hack core**](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core).
2. If you are adding this code to a custom module, and name that module *node* (as you mentioned in the comment of the code), that will conflict with the core *node* module, and might cause conflicts and break down your code.
3. If you add this code to a custom module (with a different name), then it is a wrong way to implement a hook in custom module. Follow [this guide](http://drupal.org/node/1074362) to get started with module development.
   Lets say, if you name your module "custom_search", then you should place this code in the file `custom_search.module`, and implement it in the following way:

   ```
   function custom_search_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {

   }
   ```

   Note that, I've replace the *hook* in the function name with the module name "custom_search"

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. My question was more specifically on distributing to a different solr server (for which I tried changing $env_id by making it reference - I understand it's not right and that's why mentioned that "since it messes up with existing calls."). But thanks for the pointers though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I can give a complete answer , However have a look on the search results and modules available, this may give you an idea/hint,

- http://drupal.org/node/655412

> 1) An advanced option to allow configuration of "shards". This allows Solr to do a distributed search across several cores. A Filter by site Facet.  Addition of the site host onto the extra result  information (the small text under each result).

- http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch

> Multisite search is made possible by having many sites share an index.
>   Because each "document" is stored in the index with a site and a hash
>   field, it is possible to filter by site or hash, and thus return
>   results from just one site, or from all of the sites sharing an index.

I will try to update you on this after digging  more into the module.